# Prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ exists without using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

My only idea to solve this problem was using the definition (epsilon-delta) of limits, but I couldn't come up with a conclusion.

Comment: Note that $|x| \leq \|(x, y) \|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x| \leq \|(x, y) \|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

So:

$$0 \leq \frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq |y|$$

And $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}|y|=0$$

So by the squeeze theorem you're done.

Comment: Can I use "0" as a function in the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes, this is a standard procedure when proving that the limit of a function is zero in $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Use that $$x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$$ From here we get
$$\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le \frac{xy}{\sqrt{2|xy|}}$$
and this tends to zero if $$x,y$$ tends to zero.
For $$xy>0$$ we get  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(xy)^{1/2}$$ and so on.

Comment: How can I have this conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Note: $2|xy| \le x^2+y^2 $.

$|\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}| \le $

$(1/2)\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =$

$(1/2) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Choose $\delta =2\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I didn't understand the reasoning behind the use of the inequality 2|xy|≤x^2+y^2. Also, I don't know how to convert that conclusion to the first line of the process.

Comment: +1 this is a nice approach!

Comment: Nucleus :$(x+y)^2 \ge 0$(a square), also $(x-y)^2 \ge 0$.Expand both expressions, you get $x^2+y^2 \ge -2xy$, and $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$ , means : $x^2+y^2 \ge 2|xy$|. Now  $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt \delta (=2\epsilon)$ implies $|f(x,y)-0| \lt \epsilon$. Helps a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ so both of $|x|$ and $|y|$ are less than $\delta$. I f-for example- take $z=\text{max}\{|x|,|y|\}$ so $z>=0$ and $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>|\sqrt{z+0}|$$ This can lead you t get a right proof. Here, the possible limit is zero. In fact, having a path-wise proofing make us sure that the limit is zero, so we should proof it by $\epsilon-\delta$ version.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|<\dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{2|xy|}}<\sqrt{|xy|}$$

Comment: So simple than mine!

Comment: Could you explain how can I obtain these intervals?

Comment: @mrs your description in nice.

Comment: @Nucleus $x^2+y^2\geqslant 2|xy|$. here $xy\neq0$

Comment: @Nucleus begin from $x^2+y^2\pm2xy\geqslant0$

Comment: Nosrati.Thanks, you went the other way, got rid of the square:). Greetings.